# @Html.AjaxGrid() how to format a decimal

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, grid

I've got an  @Html.AjaxGrid() (which is a new concept for me), that gets inserted in the view as like this:

```
@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("Search", new { ID = Model.ID }))
```

And then columns are added in a separate file, Search.cshtml like this:

```
....
columns.Add(x => x.ItemPrice)
    .Titled("Price")
    .Encoded(false)
    .Sortable(true)
    .Filterable(false);
```

In this example, ItemPrice is a decimal that displays on the screen:

```
1569.0000
```

How do I format it as US currency?

```
$1,569.00
```

What I've tried:

```
    columns.Add(x => x.ItemPrice.ToString("C"))
    .Titled("Price")
    .Encoded(false)
    .Sortable(true)
    .Filterable(false);
```

But that tells me that .ToString() does not accept any parameters.  Also...

```
    columns.Add(x => x.ItemPrice)
    .Titled("Price")
    .Encoded(false)
    .Sortable(true)
    .Format("#,#")
    .Filterable(false);
```

And that tells me that .Format can not be used as a method.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is:

```
    columns.Add(x => x.ItemPrice)
        .Titled("Price")
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sortable(true)
        .Filterable(false)
        .RenderedAs(c => string.Format("{0:C}", c.ItemPrice));
```